# How to reconnect a split face to its mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have accidentally pressed the <kbd>Y</kbd> key and have split a face from its mesh.

I can undo the action but I would like to know the actual command to do the opposite of split.

Merge tool options did not work (unless I am doing it wrong).
Object mode -> Join did not work.

Comment: In this case you can try: *W > remove doubles*

Comment: Hmmm, that did not work, sorry.

Comment: If you have selected everything (or at least problem part of the mesh) before proceeding with *Remove Doubles*, and if you haven't change splitted face location, then it should work. If you changed location, then I think the solution would be to select vertice of the splitted face, and adjacent of the mesh and press `Alt`+`M`>*At Last*. You should do so for every single vertex of the splitted face.

Comment: Ah, Mr. Zak, that was it. I had attempted the "Remove Doubles" immediately after pressing the y key. I needed to " have selected everything (or at least problem part of the mesh) before proceeding with Remove Doubles" (per your instructions) for this to finally work. Thank you.

Comment: Easiest one is Mesh -> Cleanup -> Merge by distance

Answer (score 8):

Being in *Edit Mode* select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>), hit <kbd>W</kbd>***-->Remove Doubles***. Now you have a consistent mesh.
[image]

You may also use a ***Undo History*** pop up menu (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) and select the step you want to get back to.
[image]
[image]

Comment: In newer versions (3.0 or so and up) "Remove Doubles" is now called "Merge by Distance"

Answer (score 3):

I had attempted the "Remove Doubles" immediately after pressing the <kbd>Y</kbd> key but this did not work.

I needed to have everything selected (<kbd>A</kbd> toggles select all, or select none) before proceeding with "Remove Doubles" for this to finally work.

Answer (score 2):

Remove doubles with option "Unselected" checked

[image]